# is there any way to validate PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID & PAYPAL_SECRET_ID are true by using 'paypal/rest-api-sdk-php' package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

how I can find the PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID and  PAYPAL_SECRET_ID are wrong so that I can show the message to the ***sender*** 
“*your receiver does not configure his Paypal account*” 
 instead of showing the white blank 
screen in case of the receiver(PayPal facilitator account) wrong credential

here is a short scene in my application, there are type  tow user

- **vendor**( vendor request for withdrawing his payment via my application)
- **admin** (admin pay against withdrawing request via Paypal)

each vendor add his own **client_id** and **secret_id** in his vendor account in my application, in case any user put the wrong credential then 
 how I can find these credential are wrong **?** 
so that I can show the suitable message to admin

**What I have done ?**
if I put correct **PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID** and **PAYPAL_SECRET_ID** then everything going fine
but when I put the wrong credential for testing then the blank screen appears

I could not identify these credential are ***true/false*** because ApiContext class object return same result weather credential are tur or false

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
class PaypalController extends Controller{

//get dynamically client_id and secret_id against a specific user

public function get_apiContext($user_id){

$bank_detail=BankDetails::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('account_type','paypal')->first();

         return new ApiContext(
            new OAuthTokenCredential(
                $bank_detail->client_id,
                $bank_detail->secret_id
            )
         );
**//for true credential(these credential store in DB)**
dd($this->get_apiContext(some_user_id));

**//for wrong credential(these credential store in DB)**
dd($this->get_apiContext(some_user_id));

 }

***//output for true credential***

ApiContext {#309 ▼
  -requestId: null
  -credential: OAuthTokenCredential {#315 ▼
    -clientId: "ASTxYaCVuy8DTvyZsGsmu9bQrEQgaIgHBK1yDnzqZGB65iZDzoK-LWtghytOn8HBsAqADQFFV0B4KsVG4"
    -clientSecret: "EEisV6THUKO7czPfNR0nW67dH2fZMvXIGxgm39hnCco_oph6JuHxF8tuda7-vLmOvs6LMGcInw5rn9psNK"
    -targetSubject: null
    -accessToken: null
    -tokenExpiresIn: null
    -tokenCreateTime: null
    -cipher: Cipher {#314 ▼
      -secretKey: "EEisV6THUKO7czPfNR0nW67dH2fZMvXIGxgm39hnCco_uioh6JuHxF8tuda7-vLmOvs6LMGcInw5rn9psNK"
    }
    -_propMap: []
  }
}



***//for the wrong credential***

ApiContext {#309 ▼
  -requestId: null
  -credential: OAuthTokenCredential {#315 ▼
    -clientId: "ASTxYaCVuy8DTvyZsGsmu9bQrEQgaIgHBK1yDponzqZGB65iZDzoK-LWtghytOn8HBsAqADQFFV0B4KsVG4aaaaaaaaaa"
    -clientSecret: "EEisV6THUKO7czPfNR0nW67dH2fZMvXIGxgm39hnCco_h6JuHjkuxF8tuda7-vLmOvs6LMGcInw5rn9psNK"
    -targetSubject: null
    -accessToken: null
    -tokenExpiresIn: null
    -tokenCreateTime: null
    -cipher: Cipher {#314 ▼
      -secretKey: "EEisV6THUKO7czPfNR0nW67ghjjdH2fZMvXIGxgm39hnCco_h6JuHxF8tuda7-vLmOvs6LMGcInw5rn9psNK"
    }
    -_propMap: []
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I was  used try-catch while configuring the PayPal gateway in my code when  wrong PayPal account information(PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID / PAYPAL_SECRET_ID  ) was given unfortunately   Catch section was not fetch exception because of the namespace for Exception was no use in my file, so i  used fully qualified name  issue resolve

Comment: //wrong code

try{
//configration code

}catch (Exception $e) {
   
//throw some exception   

  }
this code catch exception properly

try{
//configration code

}catch (\Exception $e) {
   
//throw some exception   

  }